# Styles not working in wordpress plugin | wp_enqueue_styles()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been searching the web left right and center for a solution to get the `wp_enqueue_style()` function to work but I just can't get it.

**Code Snippet**

```
//Add some styles to the script
function sreub_enqueue_styles() {

    //Use it!
    wp_enqueue_style ( 'sreubmainstyle', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'sreubmainstyle.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sreub_enqueue_styles' );
```

I have echoed the path I am using in the `wp_enqueue_style` function and it is correct but have no idea why the styles are not being applied when I put them in the CSS file?

Comment: Not that I don't trust you :) But are you sure your CSS is alright?

Answer (score 0):

Switch theme and try. or deactivate the plugin and active again. it should works. This code work for me.

```
    function sreub_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'sreubmainstyle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'sreubmainstyle.css' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sreub_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a couple of checks first to determine where the root cause lies:

**Check the path**

Let's check the path specified to the enqueue instruction.  The path you have says the CSS file is located in the same folder (and not a subfolder) as the PHP file that has the enqueue callback.

Is this the case?

Check to see where the CSS file is located in relationship to the PHP file.  If it's in a subfolder or elsewhere, you will need to modify your pathing.

For example, let's say the CSS file is located in `wp-content/your-plugin/assets/css/sreubmainstyle.css` but the PHP file which enqueues it is located in say `wp-content/your-plugin/load-assets.php`, the URL path to the CSS file would need to absolute by including the full path.

Just double check.  If the path is correct, then let's go to the next check.

**Loading Before the theme's CSS**

The theme's loads after the plugin. WordPress loads plugins first and then the theme.  Your code is pre-registering the callback with a priority of 10.  More than likely the theme is also using the default of 10.  That means the plugin's CSS will load *first* into the `<head>`.

Check the `<head>` and see if where the stylesheet is loaded in relationship to the theme.  Use Firefox or Chrome Dev Tools to inspect the HTML markup.

1. If you find it's not loaded into the DOM (meaning in the HTML markup, then we are back to an enqueue problem. If yes, then go to the next check.
2. Else, I suspect it's there but *before* the theme's ’style.css` file.  If yes, continue reading this section.

You want your styles to come after the theme to ensure yours override the theme and take a higher precedence.  In this case, you want to change the priority to something greater than the default of 10.  To do this:

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sreub_enqueue_styles', 50);`

The 50 sets the priority higher, meaning it fires later.

**Whoops, CSS is not in DOM**

Looking in the HTML markup using Firefox or Chrome, you discovered that it did not even load.  It's not there.  Okay, you know that the path is right.  Next did you load the file that is doing the enqueuing?  And did you load it before WordPress fires the event to enqueue?

Check when you are loading the file.

Answer (score 0):

try to run `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sreub_enqueue_styles' );` from the main file or make sure `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sreub_enqueue_styles' );` is run on the activation hook callback